# FROM_UNIX alternate in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, unix-timestamp

Guys I have stored unix timestamps in my MySQL database, where I was reading them using the MySQL function `FROM_UNIX()`.

Now I'm migrating the database from MySQL to PostgreSQL. In PostgreSQL, how I can read unix timestamps just like I was doing in MySQL with `FROM_UNIX()` ?

Answer (score 8):

Taken [from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html):

> to_timestamp(double precision) convert Unix epoch to time stamp

If you need parts of the created timestamp, use the [`extract`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function

```
select extract(year from to_timestamp(1284352323))
```

Comment: to_timestamp basically converts unix timestamp to readable PostgreSQL timestamp. I don't need all. I want specific things from unix timestamp. For example I want only the Year from timestamp. In MySQL is done like FROM_UNIXTIME(field,"%YY")

Comment: @user1551373: then use the `extract` function to get that from the resulting timestamp.

Comment: @user1551373 `extract` is SQL standard by the way, and should work just fine in MySQL too. `to_standard` doesn't seem to be though it's supported in Oracle and some other databases. You might want to consider a writing a wrapper function if your code needs to be portable.

Comment: @CraigRinger: what do you mean with `to_standard`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Argh, `to_timestamp` . Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT to_char(date(to_timestamp(1195374767)),'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

- to_timestamp - convert to Postgresql timestamp no unix timestamp
- date convert to date type
- to_char format output

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html

extract can do the same thing but not in one step

Comment: It's worth adding a brief note of explanation about what you're doing and a link to the docs. See @a_horse_with_no_name's answer. Your answer will probably get flagged by the low quality question moderator's system and deleted as a code-only answer with better answers present.

Comment: You can leave `date(...)` out. `to_char(to_timestamp(1195374767),'YYYY-MM-DD')`