# What changes do i need to do in my code to in php for mysql to PostgreSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, postgresql

```
  $result=mysqli_query($conn, $Sqlquery);
 $data_new=array();
 foreach($result as $row){
     $data_new[]=$row;
 }

echo json_encode($data_new,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

I am getting results in mysql by using the above code but not in PostgreSQL. I have also changed from mysqli_query to pg_query

```
$rs=pg_query($conn, $Sqlquery);
$data_new=array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($rs)) {
    $data_new[]=$row;
  }
  


echo json_encode($data_new,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

But i am getting nothing in my array . Please help

Comment: What's the value of `$Sqlquery`?

Comment: Also, just a thought, have you actually populated the new Postgres database?

Comment: $Sqlquery="SELECT COUNT(id) AS totalusers, ROUND(COUNT(id)/$numOfDays_interval,2) 
        AS avgusers, FROM_UNIXTIME(timecreated,'%Y-%m-%d') 
        AS users_date 
        FROM view_lastaccess where FROM_UNIXTIME(timecreated) >= '$time_from' 
        AND FROM_UNIXTIME(timecreated) <= '$time_to' GROUP BY 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(timecreated,'%Y-%m-%d') ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(timecreated) DESC LIMIT 60"

Comment: Please add facts (especially code) into the question text (with proper formatting), not as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the query you replied with to my question in comments, it seems that you're passing an invalid query to Postgres.

If you were correctly checking for and handling errors, you would find that `FROM_UNIXTIME()` does not exist in PG's dialect of SQL, so you will need to find an alternative and adapt your query so that it is compatible.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194416/from-unix-alternate-in-postgresql) will likely have a replacement that you can use, particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12194586/2084984) which recommends using `to_timestamp` - though you'll need to make sure your column type is compatible (I can only guess as to what you're using), though I am sure this is the culprit).

Comment: yes thanks that was the culprit and i modified it to to_timestamp and successfully fetched result by running in database but now need to fetch records using postgresql php as i was using mysqli .